# The divergence of the Stress Energy Tensor

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I have been studying general relativity and I have often seen in textbooks that the divergence of the stress energy tensor is zero.

$$T^{\mu\nu}_{;\nu} = 0$$

but is it possible to contract and replace the indices and write it as

$$\delta^\nu_\sigma T^{\mu\nu}_{;\nu} = T^{\mu\nu}_{;\sigma} = 0$$

instead? Here the semicolon ";" represents the covariant derivative. So far I have seen nothing of this sort and I would also like an explanation as to why such a thing may or may not be possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that transformation is not legit.

Your final statement (A) says that the covariant derivative of the stress-energy tensor vanishes for every component. It has three free indices which means it represents 4$\times$4$\times$4=64 real-valued equations. Your initial statement (B) states only that four-at-a-time linear combinations of those derivatives vanish. It has one free index and therefore represents 4 real equations. Here A implies B but there is no way that B can imply A without more information.

Your mistake is the term $\delta^\nu_\sigma T^{\mu\nu}_{;\nu}$. If you're using Einstein summations, **any term with three repeated indices is almost definitely wrong**. (And unless you're doing something extremely fancy, you can do without the 'almost'.) The correct transformation is

$$T^{\mu\nu}_{;\nu}=\delta^\sigma_\nu T^{\mu\nu}_{;\sigma}$$

and it adds nothing new to the conversation.  The statement $T^{\mu\nu}_{;\nu}=0$ is concise for a reason: it is the most concise expression possible for that concept. There's really nothing much you can do to it.